# Manual noodle press pasta maker sticking

Tags: pasta

I recently got a manual noodle press pasta maker and when I used it, pasta came out and started sticking. I tried to flour the pasta maker but the pasta in the middle of the mould still stuck. Olive oil also did not help.
My recipe for the dough is :

2 1/2 cups flour

3 egg yolks

teaspoon of salt

3/4 cup of water

This is the pasta maker:
[image]

Answer (score 1):

There are two things I would do here.

1. Make sure you have kneaded sufficiently. Knead until the dough comes together and does not stick to your fingers, but forms a nice cohesive ball. If you
2. Make sure that your dough is not too wet. I personally like Ruhlman's ratio for egg pasta, which is 3 parts flour to 2 parts egg, no water. In your case, that would mean 4 eggs for the 2 1/2 cups flour, and no water at all. You are using 3 eggs + 180 ml water, which is twice the liquid amount, plus water doesn't bind as well as egg.

Of the two, the kneading is the more important part. You can certainly work with wetter doughs, if they are properly kneaded, it is just a bit more fussy. But if you touch the dough and it smears/sticks like wet plaster, it is underkneaded and you should continue working it before forming it.

If your dough looks like one of these, it is not a well-kneaded egg pasta dough (note, the right picture is OK if making bread or pizza):
[image]

This is what good pasta dough looks like, before you put it into the pasta maker:
[image]

The important part is not the color (you'll get automatically from the eggs), but the smoothness. You have to be able to shape it into that ball easily with your hands, without it sticking to them.

Comment: Thanks for the advice, I think i kneaded enough as I used the hand mixer

Comment: @Joshua the hand mixer is a good option, you just need to knead for a sufficiently long time with it. I added pictures, so you can judge if your dough is kneaded enough.

Comment: Do I have to knead it until there is the window pane effect or do I need more kneading

Comment: Pasta dough doesn't feel like bread dough, it won't have a window pane effect. You have to knead until you have properly developed gluten, but in pasta dough, "properly developed gluten" does not have the same look and feel as the properly developed effect in bread dough ("window pane effect" is an intuitive way to describe that look and feel in bread dough). Look for a tight, cohesive, nonsticky consistency like in the last picture.

Comment: After trying the pasta maker, I just invested in a better pasta roller and also I think I kneaded the dough too much and had it somehow have the window pane effect. It was still good though

Answer (score 1):

Not every type of flour will deliver optimal results.

I suggest to use **coarse durum wheat flour**.

As a rule of thumb, it is **better to stay on the dry side**. Add just enough liquids (either eggs or water, or strained tomato, spinach etc.) **so that the dough does not tear** when rolled thin. You can make great pasta without any eggs as well, in fact most pasta eaten in Italy is made without.

Also, I suggest **the right tools**.

**Pasta machine**: the tool in the picture looks like it isn't capable of withstanding high pressure/torque. This may be a problem with a rather dry dough. I must say that I know nothing about oriental noodles, but for making pasta I suggest a [steel pasta machine](https://duckduckgo.com/?q=steel%20pasta%20machine%20&t=lm&iar=images&iax=images&ia=images).

I've found **drying racks** helpful also when preparing fresh noodles because they don't stick together when stored temporarily before going into the pot. This is especially helpful if you want to cook several servings at once and therefore need more time.